# Vertical alignment with display: inline-flex; combined with SVG and text

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment, tailwind-css

I have the StackBlitz set up here (I am using Tailwind):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/tailwindcss-m77ntn?file=index.html

I have a button like this:

```
<div id="button1" class="bg-gray-500 px-2 py-2 inline-flex space-x-2">
  <div class="w-5">
    &#10003;
  </div>
  <div>
    Yay
  </div>
</div>
```

Which puts the items next to each other in the containing div.

But, when I put this div next to another div - exactly the same, but containing an SVG instead of an HTML entity - then the buttons are misaligned, as you can see in the Stackblitz example.

```
<div id="button3" class="bg-gray-500 px-2 py-2 inline-flex space-x-2">
  <div class="w-5">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M5 13l4 4L19 7"></path>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div>
    Doh
  </div>
</div>
```

See:

[image: Issue example]

I would like for all the divs to align equally.

I know this is due to the height of the div containing the "tick" and where I use the SVG I am not setting a line height with any HTML characters

Comment: `align-top` to your button

Comment: @temaniAfif - nice one

Answer (score 0):

Just add `flex pt-1` classes to `#app` element

You can update your HTML

```
<div id="app" class="flex pt-1">

    <div id="button1" class="bg-gray-500 px-2 py-2 inline-flex space-x-2">
      <div class="w-5">
        ✓
      </div>
      <div>
        Yay
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="button1" class="bg-gray-500 px-2 py-2 inline-flex space-x-2">
      <div class="w-5">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
      <div>
        Yay
      </div>
    </div>

    
    
    <div id="button3" class="bg-gray-500 px-2 py-2 inline-flex space-x-2">
      <div class="w-5">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M5 13l4 4L19 7"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div>
        Doh
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```